# Yahoo Pipes: Using URL Builder to customize item.link in RSS Item Builder Module

Tags: pipe, yahoo-pipes

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=85a288a1517e615b765df9603fd604bd

I am trying to build a baseball media feed. The 'fetch data' output I am using doesn't spit out a link to the media though it does provide the video ID [item.contentID] which needs to be appended to the following URL: mlb.mlb.com/media/video.jsp?content_id=

I am lost in how to use URL Builder, String Builder, RegEx to achieve this but you can get the basic idea through what I have mapped out there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it, thanks to someone over on the Pipes message board, w/ the RegEx module. By placing it in between Fetch Data and the RSS Item Builder, I was able to replace the contentId value.

```
In [item.contentID], replace ^ with mlb.mlb.com/media/video.jsp?content_id=
```